# How to embed a ppt in a website(React App) without using iframe and with transition animations?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, system-design, google-slides

I want to know how i can embeded a ppt (or google slides link in my web App) without using iframe, in my react App.
I have seen this sort of implementation in Scrimba.
https://medium.com/scrimba/whats-new-at-scrimba-e38b9fd5ab7b

Here, User can click Import from Google slides in the top right corner, and will get slide slideshow added.

and they are not using iframe.

Any help or lead will be very helpful.
Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.